# I am new in here and am in need of help with ''communities''

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

What are the best communities on Stack Exchange for a student in FdSc Applied computing to join?

I will be learning C#, C++, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, jQuery, SQL, PHP and hopefully more stuff. I will also touch cyber security and system analysis. I'm on my first year.

Comment: Well, which ones do you want to ask a question on? Each community's scope is pretty well defined in their respective help center.

Comment: well i have placed what my interests are in my question. i have joined ''programmers'' and ''web applications'' but i feel that maybe some one in here will have a better view of my situation and experience and hint and tip me with a few more.

Comment: If you still won't use capitals, I can't tell for you a great future on the sites. Not having a high-level English is not a problem here until you are understandable, but intentionally ignoring even [the most elemental spelling rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370) isn't a really polite way of communication.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming for a moment that you're currently still at the stage where you're asking rather than answering questions, I'm going to give you what may seem like a strange answer. But it somewhat illustrates how I use Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites. I don't come to them to learn, or at least not directly. Let me explain.

Rather than trying to find the site that is right for me when learning new things, I'll actually prefer tutorials, textbooks and documentation. However, clearly I've spent quite a while on the sites in the network, so what gives ...

I end up coming here when there's trouble. When I'm stuck on something. When I see behaviour I can't explain. When I know what I want to do, when I've researched how I want to do it, but I can't seem to connect the last few dots.

Then I search (usually even via Google rather than site search) and generally I end up finding something related on one of the sites within the network. This approach has been so successful for me that even after years of participating on Stack Overflow, I still have yet to ask a question. I have plenty of questions, but most of them have been asked in some form or another.

So to me, asking on which sites you should participate, ends up with me asking a question: "What is the problem you're facing". Do your research, find how to formulate your problem, and chances are that you'll eventually end up on the correct site.

But feel free to roam around on the various [sites within the network](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Each site has a help center where you can learn about what's on-topic and how you could participate. In addition to the ones you mention [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) may be useful to you, so check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for posts related to each topic (C#, C++, etc.) by tag. Here's the link: [Stack Exchange Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags)

Comment: There are no `C#`, `C++` etc tags on Meta SE. I guess you should link to [Stack Overflow tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) if anything.

Answer (score -7):

First: most of the sites advocate a professional writing style. Please stop using "i" and a nearly complete lack of capitals. They can be interpreted as a signature of incompetence, so a professional writing style is highly encouraged.

Stack Exchange is not really like a forum, it is more like a site of collective learning and problem solving. So, you can learn and solve problems here:

The most obvious site to join is [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com), and [Super User](http://superuser.com). I would like to suggest also the [Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). It is very useful if you have joined multiple communities, understanding the same problem from multiple views (both the problems of the community - you will understand what problems and solutions a community can have by comparing them to eachother, and you will be able to investigate your more complex IT questions from multiple viewpoints).

Most sites don't like questions for recommending software, but there is a [Software Recommendation Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) for these questions.

[Here](https://stackexchange.com/sites) you can get a complete list of the Stack Exchange sites. It is useful to know them, around half of them are IT-oriented. They tend to be small, but full with very high level experts of their given field. Stack Overflow is more like a big soup.

Only joining the sites is not enough, start to post content and collect reputation.

In the beginning you will hit a problem, that your posts are voted down and your questions are closed. You will think it is unfair, and you will be partially right. Try to follow the rules, and in the case of clearly bad decisions, start a discussion about the closure on that sites meta.

Comment: @DavidPostill No, no. Be a nice guy. :-)